# Sizing WPF controls to an exact percentage

Tags: wpf, controls, sizing, actualwidth

In WPF, I want set a controls width to be, say, 97% of it's Parent controls `ActualWidth` property.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Grid panel. E.g:

```
<Border>
  <Grid>  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.97*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.03*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="97%"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Green">
   </Border>
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

Grid will occupy 100% of available border's size. First column will use 97% of it. And the rest 3% are given to border in the second column.

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Anvaka