# Limit WPF control size to a certain proportion / percentage of the parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, material-design-lite

I want to prevent these chat boxes from going over 50% of their parent (stackpanel)'s width

Like so:
[image]

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954533/sizing-wpf-controls-to-an-exact-percentage) question but I do not understand the answer

Here's my XAML

```
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="MessageViewScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Panel.ZIndex="-1">
                <StackPanel Name="MessageView" Margin="0 100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <local:UserControlMessageReceived HorizontalAlignment="Left" Loaded="UserControlMessageReceived_Loaded" Width="343" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
                    <local:UserControlMessageSent HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: As shown in that answer, use a Grid with two columns. Put the StackPanel into the Grid.

Comment: @Clemens , I still don't quite understand how to implement that information into my requirement. Any chance you could elaborate? Thank you

Comment: As said, put the StackPanel into the first column of a Grid with two columns. Try it at least. There is very helpful online documentation available with a lot of examples.